# SQL query about appointments

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime-generation

Suppose we have this table..

```
CREATE TABLE `appointments` (
  `idappointments` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timeStart` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeEnd` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idappointments`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

**assumption**

Suppose that a range between timeStart and timeEnd cant exist again... I mean that if we intersect all the ranges in the table the result would be EMPTY ,0 , null.An appointment cant cooexist with another..

So what i want to do is a time suggestion if the desired time is occupied...
A proposal before and a proposal after the desired time....

So i was wondering instead of writing code to do this if i could write an SQL query to find the nearest empty ranges......

Ex.. timeStart - NEAREST_TO_TIMESTART_TIMEEND >'10 minutes'  whereas 10 minutes the duration

Comment: FYI, in SQL `NULL` and `0` are different :)

Comment: If you're only capturing the time, how do you know what day the appoint is to fall on?

Comment: I just simplified the table for here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have recursive functionality, so you're left with using the NUMBERS table trick -

1. Create a table that only holds incrementing numbers - easy to do using an auto_increment:

   ```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`numbers`;
   CREATE TABLE  `example`.`numbers` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
2. Populate the table using:

   ```
   INSERT INTO NUMBERS
     (id)
   VALUES
     (NULL)
   ```

   ...for as many values as you need.
3. Use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to construct a list of dates, increasing the days based on the NUMBERS.id value.  Replace "2010-01-01" and "2010-01-02" with your respective start and end dates (but use the same format, YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) -

   ```
   SELECT x.dt
     FROM (SELECT TIME(DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) * 15 MINUTE)) AS dt
             FROM numbers n
            WHERE DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) * 15 MINUTE) <= '2010-01-02' ) x
   ```
4. LEFT JOIN onto your table of data based on the datetime portion.

### This will show you the first available slot:

```
       SELECT x.dt
      FROM (SELECT TIME(DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) * 15 MINUTE)) AS dt
              FROM numbers n
             WHERE DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) * 15 MINUTE) <= '2010-01-02' ) x
    LEFT JOIN APPOINTMENTS a ON x.dt BETWEEN a.timestart AND a.timeend
        WHERE a.idappoinment IS NULL
          AND x.dt > @your_minimum_datetime
     ORDER BY x.dt
        LIMIT 1
```

### This will show you availability for the entire day:

```
       SELECT x.dt,
              CASE 
                WHEN a.idappoinment IS NULL THEN 'available'
                ELSE 'booked'
              END AS isbooked 
      FROM (SELECT TIME(DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) * 15 MINUTE)) AS dt
              FROM numbers n
             WHERE DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) * 15 MINUTE) <= '2010-01-02' ) x
    LEFT JOIN APPOINTMENTS a ON x.dt BETWEEN a.timestart AND a.timeend
     ORDER BY x.dt
```

### Why Numbers, not Dates?

Simple - dates can be generated based on the number, like in the example I provided.  It also means using a single table, vs say one per data type.

Comment: great... But would this cause a limitation to the duration ?

Comment: @Parhs: You can alter the minute value generation to suit your needs - it can be changed to seconds if you need that much precision.

Comment: If i change the precision to the minute would be ok but then how i would know if 5 slots of one minute(continius) is available?

Comment: @Parhs: Use the order by: `ORDER BY x.dt`

Comment: i mean the source code that would suggest to the user the neaest time available..Your method is great to find the available slots

Comment: @Parhs: I updated the answer to show both viewing a day, and getting the first available slot.  However `LIMIT 1` wouldn't show you sequencial openings, just the first opening.